# i keep receiving the error called System.FormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a system that is to have GridView with a select option to select the data stored in a particular row by its primary key ID.

This code works just fine on another page to perform the exact same functionality

```
    protected void lnk_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int objectiveID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("objectiveViewByID", con);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectiveID", objectiveID);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
        con.Close();
        hfobjectiveID.Value = objectiveID.ToString();
        txtAudience.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["audience"].ToString();
        txtCondition.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["condition"].ToString();
        txtBloom.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["bloom_level"].ToString();
        txtVerb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["verb"].ToString();
        txtProduct.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["product"].ToString();
        btnSave.Text = "Update";
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I expect the code to repopulate the input fields that were used to populate the database.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `int objectiveID = ...` What's the value of `(sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument`?

Comment: And more generally, use a debugger to identify the precise line where you get this or any exception.

Comment: Hi @phillay, welcome to SO. Please post the entire exception stack, not just the name of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a format exception, it could give an error here if the ToInt32 method input is some non number value.

```
int objectiveID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
```

Other potential areas are the following code, if the value, for instance, dtbl.Rows[0]["audience"] is null.
But that would be a different exception though. You could put a break point at the top and see which line crashing.

```
hfobjectiveID.Value = objectiveID.ToString();
txtAudience.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["audience"].ToString();
txtCondition.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["condition"].ToString();
txtBloom.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["bloom_level"].ToString();
txtVerb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["verb"].ToString();
txtProduct.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["product"].ToString();
```